# A question on the sets $V(p,\epsilon)$ in the book of Rudin

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am reading the book of Rudin's functional analysis. Let us start with a vector space $X$ over the reals and we let $P$ be a separating family of seminorms on $X$. For each $p\in P$ and $\epsilon >0$, write 
$$V(p,\epsilon)=\{x\in X: p(x)<\epsilon\}.$$
Rudin claimed that the family $P$ induces a locally convex topology $\tau$, hence making $X$ a locally convex TVS, with the property that every $p$ in $P$ is $\tau$-continuous.

**Question.** Do the sets $V(p,\epsilon)$ belong to $\tau$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets $V(p,\varepsilon)$ belong to $\tau$ by definition. $\tau$ consists of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of elements of the form $V(p,\varepsilon,x)$ for some $x\in X, p\in P$ and $\varepsilon>0$, where $V(p,\varepsilon,x)=\{u\in X,p(x-u)<\varepsilon\}$.

Comment: Thanks. I raised that question because by looking at the set $V(p,\epsilon)$, its just simply equal to $p^{-1}([0,\epsilon)).$ Here, $[0,\epsilon)$ is not open and so I canot invoke the continuity of $p$.

Comment: $V(p,\varepsilon)=p^{—1}(-1,\varepsilon)$, which is open.

Comment: I got confused with the description of your $\tau$. Does it refers to the arbitrary unions of the translates of finite intersections of the sets $V(p,\epsilon)$?

Comment: Actually, yes (otherwise, we would only get neighborhood of the origin).

Comment: I got it. I don't have to force the issue at $[0,\epsilon)$. Anyway, $-1<0\le p(x)<\epsilon$ for any $x\in X$.